# Object collection to JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have a RESTful web service (Spring, Hibernate, c3p0, Sybase) running on Tomcat.

It is a search service and returns back a collection of objects depending upon the search criteria. Each object has a pretty deep structure of included objects inside them, sometimes running into a hundred objects (approx). Currently, after we have received the collection we change them into XMLs and send that as a response.

For reasons that is beyond the scope of the question here, I need to respond back in JSON now, along with XML. So, the client of the REST service could choose to get the response in XML or JSON.

With that context, the question now is

1. What is the suggested framework / library to handle the requirement of creating a JSON response from a collection of objects (with each object potentially having around 100 or so objects embedded into it). I am currently looking at Jackson. But if you have used anything else and have got good / bad results, please let me know.
2. What is a good way of handling the request for two different types of response i.e. XML and JSON, to be dolled out from the same service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is excellent, look no further.

Jackson actually supports JAXB annotations, so you can use it for both JSON and XML: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

There's an example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-restful/) on how to use `HttpMessageConverter` to configure different representations.